# Adding a timer to the Kinect Click function C#

Tags: c#, kinect

I have created a click function for Kinect without using any gestures.. its simple and it works.. however i want the function to wait.. my counter isnt seem to be working .. what I want to do is.. IF my hand is on the button for lets say more than 3 seconds.. then return true ..any method to do it? Counter doesnt seem to be working

```
  public bool KinectClick(int x,int y)
            {

                if ((x >= position.X && x <= position.X +position.Width) && (y >= position.Y && y <= position.Y + position.Height))
               {
                 //  time.Start();
                   int counter = 0;

                   while (true)
                   {
                       counter++;

                       if (counter >= 8000)
                       {
                           return true;
                           counter = 0;


                       }
                   }

               }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a DispatcherTimer to accomplish the same thing you are trying to do.  A simple form could look something like this:

```
private DispatcherTimer hitTestTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
private int timerCount = 5;

public MyConstructor() {
  hitTestTimer.Tick += OnHitTestTimerTick;
  hitTestTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
}

private void OnHitTestTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (timerCount > 1)
  {
    timerCount--;
  }
  else
  {
    // CLICK!
  }
}
```

You can add flags that toggle when you first enter your object, and check that to verify if you have (or haven't) left the object since the last timer tick.